# WCF Get User Identity When Using Windows but still allow Anonymous Credentials

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, iis, soap

I want to lock down some of my WCF methods while allowing others to be used by anonymous.

Currently I am using System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name to determine the login of the requester, otherwise I assume anonymous.

This works fine with the configuration below when I use a domain account or a local account.  However, when I hit it using the .\LocalSystem (nt authority\system) account (anonymous) I get a "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials."

Thanks in advance for any help you can give to allow me to pull the identity when it's there but assume anonymous (and let them through) when it's not?

My Current Configuration
- IIS Authentication = Windows and Anonymous = Enabled
- IIS Authorization Rules = Everyone and Anonymous = Allowed
- Security Mode = Transport
- Transport clientCredentialType = Windows

```
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding.../>
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
. . . 
<!-- Authorization Rules Allow Anonymous -->
<security>
  <authorization>
    <add accessType="Allow" users="?" />
  </authorization>
</security>
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out the problem, maybe someone has a better way to do this.

When the client is part of a domain (trusted) it works with either a domain account, local account, and even the local system (nt authority\system)...however if the client is NOT part of a domain (workgroup) then it works with a domain account, local account, but NOT the local system....